# How to capture 20 digit numeric or floating number to number field in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I got a requirement to validate the number field which can occupy 20 numeric digits or 16 numeric digits and 4 decimal point values maximum. And also + and - signs shouldn't be calculated in this 20 digits.

Examples:

1. 12345678901234567890 - Pass
2. +12345678901234567890 - Pass
3. -12345678901234567890 - Pass
4. 1234567890123456.7890 - Pass
5. +1234567890123456.7890 - Pass
6. -1234567890123456.7890 - Pass
7. -12345678901234567.890 - Pass
8. 123456789012345.67890 - Fail
9. 123456789012345678901  - Fail
10. 1234567890             - Pass
11. 1.1                    - Pass

Any thoughts how could we validate these kind of numbers?

Comment: datatype of this field was declared as number(35,10)

Comment: If it is defined as number datatype, how do you have '+' signs in the data?

Comment: A regular expression solution is probably possible, but wouldn't be easy. I would recommend you to add regex to your tags if you would prefer a regular expression solution. Perhaps one of the regex wizard on SO can offer assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Function**

Added the explanation as comments. You can the use the format model `SFM99999999999999999990.9999` to validate your number. Exception raised would means, the input doesn't match the format.

```
create or replace function validateMe(str IN  VARCHAR2)
return
varchar2
as
STR_COPY VARCHAR2(4000);
RESULT NUMBER;
BEGIN
/* Prefix the Sign by default */
if(SUBSTR(str,1,1) NOT IN ('+','-')) THEN
STR_COPY := '+' || STR;
else
STR_COPY := STR;
end if;

/* Check if the length is > 21 -- Including the sign and excluding decimal */
if(length(REPLACE(STR_COPY,'.')) > 21 ) then
  return 'Fail';
end if;

/* Use the TO_NUMBER() function to validate */
RESULT := to_number(STR_COPY,'SFM99999999999999999990.9999');

RETURN 'Pass';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
/* Exception means Failure */
  RETURN 'Fail';
END validateMe;
/
```

**Query:**

```
with mydata(str) as
(
select '12345678901234567890.56' from dual
union all
select '123456789012345678.56' from dual
union all
select '+12345678901234567890' from dual
union all
select '-12345678901234567890' from dual
union all
select '1234567890123456.7890' from dual
union all
select '+1234567890123456.7890' from dual
union all
select '-1234567890123456.7890' from dual
union all
select '-12345678901234567.890' from dual
union all
select '123456789012345.67890' from dual
union all
select '123456789012345678901' from dual
union all
select '1234567890' from dual
union all
select '1.1' from dual
)
select str,validateMe(str) from mydata;
```

Comment: Nice solution! Although the specific exception VALUE_ERROR could be handled instead of the generic OTHERS as a best practice.

Comment: Thanks ravi. was able to create solution to my problem with this as base